# gcloud, where's the code? How can I update the deployed code manually?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I deployed a local project using gcloud command since there everything OK. I'm getting a 500 error in the browser, but I still have hundreds of questions. Where's the code? What is doing gcloud behind the scenes when I do a deploy? Why do I see 3 instances when I just deployed just one project?

I did SSH to each of the three compute instances I see and I couldn't find the code. I want to do something very silly and easy, just go to the index.php file and do `echo '1';die;` to check that's the code I can play with to make my project work on Google Platform.

Because I'm noob on this I won't be able to tweak my project perfectly to work on Google Cloud at first, so it's probably silly but a must!

My current and only config file:

```
runtime: php
vm: true

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
```

Comment: You SSHed in to the instances? So to clarify, you are using the flexible environment?

Comment: As far as I know, the flexible environment doesn't have a default image for PHP. Where did you get the PHP Docker image you are using?

Comment: I'm in VM instances page inside Compute Engine.

Comment: So are you saying you are not using AppEngine at all then? Have you set up a web server on Compute Engine?

Comment: I'm using php as the runtime value. I had to delete Docker file because the gcloud command didn't want to deploy the app if that file was present.

Comment: No, I followed the PHP Hello World tutorial, which doesn't mention to create a web server anywhere and I replicate the same steps to deploy my PHP app.

Comment: Well, I'm quite confused about what you are actually running. If you deployed a regular AppEngine PHP app then there should not be any instances listed under Compute Engine. You can't SSH in to regular AppEngine instances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113964/discussion-between-pablo-ezequiel-leone-signetti-and-chris).

Comment: Could you link the tutorial you are following? AFAIK `runtime: php` is no longer allowed on regular AppEngine and never worked on the flexible environment, which you are using because you specified `vm: true`.

Comment: @Chris There IS a default PHP image [here](http://github.com/googlecloudplatform/php-docker) for App Engine Flexible, but it is in development.

Comment: @BrentShaffer Thanks. That's useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the AppEngine Flexible Environment (what used to be called Managed VMs). This environment uses Docker to build an image out of your application code and run it in a container.

See the [Additional Debugging](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/logging-application-events#understanding_the_code) part of the Managed VMs PHP tutorial for more info on how to debug on the machine. After SSHing into an instance, you are on the host machine, but you still need to run additional commands to access the *container*, which is where your application code is running. The following command will get you on your machine:

```
sudo docker exec -t -i gaeapp /bin/bash
```

Once there, you can edit your running application by running the following commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install vim       # or your editor of choice
vi /app/public/index.php  # I am assuming this is where your file is
```

Yes, you have to install vim on the container because it will not be installed by default, as this is your production image.

*Also* be sure to check the Logging page in Developer Console, as that is where the 500 error message will be logged, and it's a lot easier than going through these steps!